# Representing inner if else block using Optional class Java

Tags: java

```
if(someObject != null){
     if(someObject.someAttribute.equals(someValue){
         return someOtherValue;
     } else {
         return someObject.someAttribute;
     }
} else return null;
```

I was unable to figure Out a way of writing inner if else condition using Optional.How do handle else condition after the filter?

```
Optional.ofNullable(someObject).map(a -> a.someAttribute).filter(a->a.equals(someValue)).map(a ->someOtherValue)// I'm stuck after this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` is not appropriate for this use case. You can write:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(someObject)
               .map(a -> a.someAttribute)
               .map(a -> a.equals(someValue) ? someOtherValue: a);
```

If you want to return `null` when `someObject` is `null`, just add:

```
               .orElse(null);
```

But if that's your goal, it makes little sense to use Optional in the first place.

Comment: No it returns an empty Optional.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to figure out how we can return null in case `someObject` is null? I need to return null if `someObject` is null. Is it possible to edit your answer?

Comment: @BalarajV If you need to return null, why do you want to use Optional? The purpose of that class is precisely to avoid returning null...